# Proving following function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider following piecewise function 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0&\text{if}\, x \not \in [0,1], \\
 0 &\text{if}\, x \in \mathbb{Q} \bigcap [0,1],\\
 1 &\text{if}\, x \in \mathbb{I} \bigcap [0,1].
\end{cases}
$$

I have to show that above function is discontinuous on $[0,1]$ . I can show that function is discontinuous on $(0,1)$ as follows and I am unable to show that $f(x)$ is discontinuous on endpoints $0,1$

$f$ is discontinuous on $(0,1)$

- consider arbitrary $a \in (0,1)$
- since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence $(x_n) \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow a $ (entirely  in $\mathbb{Q}$ converging to a) then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) =0 $
- Now similarly, $\mathbb{I} $ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence $(y_n) \subseteq \mathbb{I} \rightarrow a $ (entirely  in $\mathbb{I}$ converging to a)  now we cannot directly conclude that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(y_n) = 1$ But we have to show that sequence enters $[0,1]$ eventually
- consider $\epsilon = \min\{|a-0|,|a-1|\}$ then there exists $N$ s.t forall $n \geq N$ $|y_n -a| < \epsilon$ (this is where $|a|>0$ is important) Now we have that sequence is entirely in $[0,1]$ from which we can conclude that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(y_n) = 1$ which proves that function is discontinuous at a.

arguing $f$ is discontinuous on $0$.

- we can use same argument as above to conclude that $\lim_{n \rightarrow} f(x_n) = 0$ cause $f$ is zero outside $[0,1]$ too.But for showing $\lim y_n = 1$ I need irrational sequence that is entirely in $[0,1].$ Here I cannot use density argument because it doesn't guarantee sequence that is entirely in $[0,1]$ nor can I think of irrational sequence that is entirely in $[0,1]$ converging to $0$

Could someone guide from here?

Comment: $a_n=2^{1/2-n}$ is an irrational sequence which converges to $0$ yet we have $a_n\in(0,1)$ for $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(\frac {\sqrt 2} n) =1$ for all $n$ and $f(0)=0$. Since $\frac {\sqrt 2} n \to 0$ it follows that $f$ is not continuous at $0$. Similarly consider $f( 1-\frac {\sqrt 2} n))$ to see that $f$ is not continuous at $1$.

Comment: Thanks for that simple sequence ! Just a minor correction $\sqrt{2} (1 - \frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow \sqrt{2}$ I think what you meant to write is $1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n} $

Comment: You are right. I have edited the answer.